# Command Line or Utility To Sync Target Directory With Source Directory

Tags: file, copy, delete-file, overwrite, delete-directory

Is there such a command or the like in copy, xcopy, or robocopy that will copy the entire contents of a source directory that

1. overwrites existing target subdirectories and files,
2. adds target subdirectories and files that did not already exist, AND (the big 'un),
3. deletes target subdirectories and files that do not exist in the source directory?

Comment: Do you really mean DOS (The early 90's operating system) or do you mean command line? Because if you really mean DOS many answers (like foxidrives' robocopy one) will not work for you due to the software would be unable to run under the DOS OS.

Comment: Thanks. I meant command line and have changed the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Robocopy` with the `/mir` switch will give you a mirror backup.

A benefit is that it does not copy files which have the same size and timestamp to save time and needless copying.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have to look to [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It is not under active developpement but I've used it without any problem to sync directories between XP and Linux directories. Its main advantage is that is able to sync directories even when modifications can happen to both sides.
Under Windows, it can be used through command line or with a IHM (but you must read the manual ...)